# how to create a new pipeline dynamically when running another pipeline in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am fairly new to Jenkins so I am looking for suggestion to how I can achieve this. Right now I am doing migration using Jenkins pipeline which performs several tasks, etc.. I would like to know if it is possible to create another pipeline (which would be a copy from another) on runtime of the pipeline I am running.  I have done some and could not find anything specific like this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking exactly. But let me try to answer.

if your requirement is to create a new Job using an existing Job there is a Copy From option when creation a new Pipeline.

[image]

If you want to programmatically create a new JOb you can use the following groovy script to do it.

```
def jobToCopy = "OldJob"
def newJobName = "NEWJOB"

def j = Jenkins.instance

def copyJob = j.getItemByFullName(jobToCopy)

def script = copyJob.getDefinition().getScript()
def flowDefinition = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition(script, true)

def job = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob(j, newJobName)
job.definition = flowDefinition
job.setConcurrentBuild(copyJob.isConcurrentBuild()) // You can add other options as nneded like this
job.save()
Jenkins.instance.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general Pipeline cannot call pipeline.
You have to either use build job step to use functionality of another pipline.
Or you move common steps to a Library which can be used by several pipelines.